# Provide default values for python dictionary while keeping reference to original object

Tags: python

I have the following python dictionary:

```
box = {
    'name': 'Test', 
    'length': 10, 
    'width': 20
}
```

I need to keep a reference to this object when passing it into a function that modifies it. 
The function will provide missing default information (`height` in this example):

```
def update_box(params): 
    defaults = {
        'name': 'Default', 
        'length': 5, 
        'width': 5, 
        'height': 5
    }

    defaults.update(params)
    params = defaults

    return params
```

Now I need to access properties of `box` from outside the function. For example:

```
box = {
    'name': 'Test', 
    'length': 10, 
    'width': 20
}

update_box(box)

print box['name']  # should output 'Test'
print box['height']  # should output 5
```

Of course, this doesn't work because the `params = default` line in the `update_box`
function reassigns `params` to `defaults`, for which there is no reference outside of `update_box`.
If I remove that line, then `box` is not modified.

What I would like to do is have some sort of inverse of the dict `update()` method that will 
allow me to "fill in the blanks" for the object with default values while still keeping a reference to the original object. 
What is the best way to do this?

Also, This example is simplified, so I can't just use the return value from `update_box`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use `params.update(defaults)`?

Comment: Because that will overwrite values in `params`. Printing `box['name']` would result in "Default" instead of "Test"

Comment: Note: In Python, unquoted keys in dict literals are variables, not strings. `{name: 'Test'}` will try to look up the `name` variable and use its value as a key.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112. I updated my question accordingly to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just update in both directions:

```
defaults.update(params)
params.update(defaults)
```

The first update ensures that the values originally in params are preserved, while the second modifies params directly.

Or, just do the update manually:

```
for k in defaults:
    params.setdefault(k, defaults[k])
```

However, a better option might be to simply return a new dict, rather than directly modifying the original one.

Comment: Why not `setdefault`?

Comment: Sure, `setdefault` is simpler.